# Group by, count and multiply

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a rather simple SQL request but I can't quite wrap my head around how this is supposed to work. So... I have this

```
SELECT
    VILLAGE.ID_VILLAGE,
    VILLAGE.NOM_VILLAGE,
    VILLAGE.PAYS,
    COUNT(SEJOUR.DATE_SEJOUR)*SEJOUR.NB_PERSONNES as NB_TOTAL_NUITS
FROM
    SEJOUR
        INNER JOIN
            RESERVATION ON RESERVATION.ID_RESERVATION = SEJOUR.ID_RESERVATION
        INNER JOIN
            VILLAGE ON VILLAGE.ID_VILLAGE = RESERVATION.ID_VILLAGE
GROUP BY
VILLAGE.ID_VILLAGE,
VILLAGE.NOM_VILLAGE,
VILLAGE.PAYS,
SEJOUR.NB_PERSONNES
```

Which returns this answer:

```
ID_VILLAGE                              NOM_VILLAGE     PAYS       NB_TOTAL_NUITS
--------------------------------------- --------------- ---------- --------------
4                                       Kouros          Grèce      7
1                                       Casa-Dali       Espagne    188
2                                       Porto-Nuevo     Espagne    126
1                                       Casa-Dali       Espagne    12
2                                       Porto-Nuevo     Espagne    3
1                                       Casa-Dali       Espagne    148
4                                       Kouros          Grèce      12
1                                       Casa-Dali       Espagne    65
1                                       Casa-Dali       Espagne    36
```

But I need it to only return me 4 answers, which would be the total of those grouped by, like say 1 would have to give me 400+ on the NB_TOTAL_NUITS field, I can't seem to get those grouped up further and still get the required multiplication to get the correct values, can someone please enlighten me as to how this is properly done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just realised I could use the sum function....

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, just realised the obvious awnser myself... use SUM()...

Comment: Please expand your answer, it might help future users

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).